# Accept params from urls with python

Tags: python, python-requests, aws-lambda, mailgun

I will be hosting the following code in an AWS Lambda function.

```
def indoctrination(params=params):
time1 = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1)
time2 = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=2)
time3 = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=3)
requests.post('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/indoc@{}/members'.format(domain_url),
            auth=auth,
            data={'subscribed': True,
                  'address': email,
                  'name': name})
email_1 = requests.post('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/{}/messages'.format(domain_url),
            auth=auth,
            data={"from": from_email,
                  "to": '{} <{}>'.format(name, email),
                  "subject": "Welcom to Python Financial",
                  "html": open("templates/email1.html")})
print 'Response status code: ', email_1.status_code
print 'Data: ', email_1.json()
email_2 = requests.post('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/{}/messages'.format(domain_url),
            auth=auth,
            data={"from": from_email,
                  "to": '{} <{}>'.format(name, email),
                  "subject": "Notes and Pizza!",
                  "html": open("templates/email2.html"),
                  "o:deliverytime": time1.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000")})
print 'Response status code: ', email_2.status_code
print 'Data: ', email_2.json()
email_3 = requests.post('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/{}/messages'.format(domain_url),
            auth=auth,
            data={"from": from_email,
                  "to": '{} <{}>'.format(name, email),
                  "subject": "Your questions answered",
                  "html": open("templates/email3.html"),
                  "o:deliverytime": time2.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000")})
print 'Response status code: ', email_3.status_code
print 'Data: ', email_3.json()
email_4 = requests.post('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/{}/messages'.format(domain_url),
            auth=auth,
            data={"from": from_email,
                  "to": '{} <{}>'.format(name, email),
                  "subject": "Why are we not doing this?",
                  "html": open("templates/email4.html"),
                  "o:deliverytime": time3.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000")})
print 'Response status code: ', email_4.status_code
print 'Data: ', email_4.json()
```

I need to be able to pass parameters to the url where this function is hosted in order to pass in the "name" and "email" variables from another application. The name and email variables will be formatted into the url when the function is called but how do I receive them in this function?

Comment: what do you mean by receive them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after some trial and error. I just needed to put my name and email variables within `request.args.get()` and then `from flask import request`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using API Gateway and aws lambda proxy integration, then whatever you pass to GET as params, like param1=something&param2=somethingelse ends up in dictionary under `event` object, like so:

```
def indoctrination(event, context):
    print(event['queryStringParameters']['param1'])
    print(event['queryStringParameters']['param2'])
```